# How to get Window Explorer to display preview icons for Visio diagrams consistently?

Tags: thumbnails, visio, explorer

I have a folder with a large number of Visio (.vsdx) diagrams it in.  Because there are so many, I would like to be able to switch to the Large Icon view in Windows Explorer to easily find the diagram I wish to edit.   When I do so, half the files are displayed as preview thumbnails and half are not and there seems to be no rhyme or reason about why.

I have found various procedures by googling suggesting resetting the Windows Explorer thumbnail database but this has no effect.   I am not even sure if this is a Window Explorer problem or something about Visio not generating thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

For one of the files that doesn't show a thumbnail, open in Visio, then select **File** -> **Info** then hover over the **Properties** area and it will offer you **Advanced Properties** and check that **Save Picture Preview** is checked.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description of how to find that option. However, it's greyed out for me.   Upon investigation, I suspect it has to do with havin a diagram based on an old template.   Any idea how to fix?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I doubt it is anything to do with the age of the template. If the files are in .vsdx format then that is the latest Visio file format.